# Insert special character XML to SQL

Tags: sql, xml, character

I'm trying to update a column of type XML.

Text to be inserted in the XML fields: "& Decision **↨‼** Agreement"

Text converted to XML: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Informations xmlns="http://monschema"><Text lGic="fdf475bc-9fed-4f61-b321-f81949cb51ca" id="71e231e6-ecbd-4848-ba6f-004bdddefb79">&amp; Décision &#x12; &#x13; Accord</Text></Informations>`

Error: Msg 9420, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
XML parsing: line 1, character 263 character non-compliant XML

I do not understand why the character with ascii code "&#x12" has a problem.

If I replace &#x12 by &#x20, it works !

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This link may help you out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkediandas2/thread/7bb66f58-df7d-4a8a-a53e-80a4b3d6b38c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

This character is from a SQL obtenues view on ORACLE database.
The character -> on ORACLE Is interpreted by ↨ on SQL SERVER.

I'll do a replace in my view

Answer (score 1):

The character references `&#x12;` and `&#x13;` denote control characters that are disallowed in XML 1.0. The real problem here is that they do not denote the characters you have in the text. The characters “↨‼” are U+21A8 UP DOWN ARROW WITH BASE and U+203C DOUBLE EXCLAMATION MARK, so they should be written as `&#x21a8;&#x203c;`.

The reason why get the odd character references is probably that in the CP437 encoding, “↨‼” are placed in code positions 12 and 13 (hex.). So this is an encoding confusion, and some conversion has applied a wrong conversion. In XML, the numbers in character references always mean Unicode code numbers.

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I converte a lot of text in XML
I'm using SQL "FOR XML PATH"
so I can not test if each character is below the ascii code 20. treatment will be too long

Put my XML version 1.1 is a good method, but refuses SQL SERVER.

Comment: Using XML 1.1, even if it were possible, would not solve the problem. It still would not make the references denote the correct characters. I think you need to find out where the incorrect operation on encodings takes place.

Answer (score 0):

These control characters are [not supported in XML version 1.0 documents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Valid_characters).

You should be able to change your version to 1.1 in the `version` attribute of the document, in which case the document should validate.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I did not know. 

but when I replace version 1.0 by 1.1, SQL SERVER return the error: XML declaration syntax incorrect

Comment: Jukka's comment seems correct that these don't seem to be the characters you want anyway.